# Compatibility issue for for IE versions above 8

Tags: javascript

I am facing compatibility issue on IE11. Code was working fine till IE8 and after this its not. We are using our own frame work. But i am unsure is it related to framework or any other issue.
One such error i got in console is:
InvalidCharacterError.
code snippet:

```
function makeScrollableTable(tbl,scrollFooter,height){
  var c, pNode, hdr, ftr, wrapper, rect;

  if (typeof tbl == 'string') tbl = document.getElementById(tbl);

  pNode = tbl.parentNode;
  fixTableWidth(tbl);

  c = container.length;
  container[c] = document.createElement('<SPAN style="height: 100; overflow: auto;">'); //>>> here only its throwing an error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only **tag name** to create dom element:

```
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.style.height = '100px';
span.style.overflow = 'auto';

container[c] = span;
```

Comment: But i need to assign the space to array container. In my code container is basically defined as array.So will it work if i just do above modification?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that builds elements with option CSS style rules.

```js
function createEl(tagName, options) {
  options = options || {};
  let css = options.css || {},
      el = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (let prop in css) el.style[prop] = css[prop];
  return el;
}

container[c] = createEl('SPAN', { css : { height: 100, overflow: 'auto' } });
```

---

Advanced Version

```js
function createEl(tagName, options) {
  options = options || {};
  let attrs = options.attrs || {},
      css = options.css || {},
      el = document.createElement(tagName);
  for (let prop in css) el.style[prop] = css[prop];
  for (let name in attrs) el.setAttribute(name, attrs[name]);
  if (options.text !== undefined) el.innerHTML = options.text;
  return el;
}

let spanEl = createEl('SPAN', {
  attrs : {
    class : 'foo'
  },
  css : {
    height : '100px',
    overflow : 'auto',
    background : 'DarkGrey',
    color : 'White'
  },
  text : 'Hello World'
});

document.body.appendChild(spanEl);
```

```css
.foo { padding: 0.5em; }
```